# Java sockets and maintaining a constant connection

Tags: java, sockets

I'm currently having a problem with maintaining a connection(I feel like this is poorly worded "maintaining a connection") between my client and the server(not a connection but rather staying in the same method). Here's my code:(ill explain the problem more after it)

Client:

```
try{ 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Type *R for registration, " );
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            int port = 13333;
            Socket mySock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(
                    new InputStreamReader(mySock.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream( mySock.getOutputStream());
            out.println(line);

            while(in.hasNextLine()){    
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                String s = scan.nextLine();
                out.println(s);
            }

            mySock.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int port = 13333;
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true){
            Socket connection = socket.accept();

            User request = new User(connection);

            Thread thread = new Thread(request);

            thread.start();

        }
```

Serverhelper(User class):

```
final class User implements Runnable {
    private static FileWriter fw;
    private static boolean flag = false;
    private  Socket socket;

    public User (Socket socket) throws Exception{
        this.socket = socket;

    }
    private Scanner scan;
    private PrintStream out;

    public void run() {
        try{
            UserInput();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private  void UserInput() throws Exception{
        scan = new Scanner(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        String input = scan.next();

        if(input.equals("*R")){
            Register();
    }

    }


    private void Register() throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{            
            scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            fw = new FileWriter("info.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter txtfile = new PrintWriter(bw);  



            //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            out.println("Enter a username: ");
            String username = scan.nextLine();
            out.println("Enter a password: ");
            String password = scan.nextLine();
            txtfile.println(username + " " + password);
            txtfile.flush();
            txtfile.close();


        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**This is what happens. Initially I start up my server, then I start up the client and enter *R into the console which then returns the string "Enter a username: ". So my server and client is working however after this I'm lost because I then proceed to enter a username to send to the server. This doesn't get picked up by my userInput method in user class because its only scanning for *R and I'm not staying inside my register method in user class. Is there a way to maintain my position(stay in the register method)? This would be ideal but im lost.

Comment: one would think you'd want a loop in the server code, in UserInput

Comment: Looks like your thread would soon terminate

Comment: ok so after the initial *R by client and response by server of "enter a username" my thread terminates?

Comment: Can you tell us what output your program produces? Also I don't think you should wrap two scanners around the same input stream, as they may buffer, so the first ma read input which you then want to get from the second Scanner -- just create the one Scanner and pass it to `Register`.

Comment: Thanks for answers i get it working just looped on the run() thats all